# Add expand functionality to images

Tags: feature-request, images

When we add images to posts, they're often shrunk to fit the web page (reduction of the width and height). I suspect this is done automatically by the HTML.

However, some times, we need to see the bigger picture (literally).

I often edit posts such as [Virus hides files, shrinks total capacity](https://superuser.com/questions/936811/virus-hides-files-shrinks-total-capacity) and add the option to view the large image by simply adding the image as a link.

Can/should this feature be enabled as standard? To have a link (some how) which shows the full version when ever we add a graphic (or at least, where applicable)?

Already asked here [Add expand functionality to images](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9489/add-expand-functionality-to-images/949) (not sure if cross posting in meta is OK or not, if not I will delete the SU one)