# Close vote dup number count background splits apart

Tags: bug

I went to close [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260128/add-expand-functionality-to-images) that was in the close votes queue as a duplicate. The current dup close vote count for the question with the blue background was 2. Using windows 8.1 with latest version of firefox. Is this a bug that it breaks the blue background onto the next line like this? Shouldn't it stick together?

[image]